# mongoose — Array variable in query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a mongoose query that allows me to find a document with a populated array, where the name of the array is stored in a variable. I've tried various syntaxes, using [square brackets], etc, and I've searched but can't find anything that works.

```js
var arrayName = req.params.abbreviation + "Films";
console.log(arrayName); //documentaryFilms

FilmModel.findOne({
  $and: [
    { incomplete: false },
    { [arrayName].[0]: { $exists: true } }
...
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$size` operator to get the length of the array.

```
FilmModel.aggregate(
[
     {
       $addFields: {
        "size_of_array": {
          $size: "$abcFilms"
        }
       }
     }
     { 
       $match: { "size_of_array": { $gt: 0 } } 
     }
])
```

If you want to filter based on an element with index `n` in an array take a look at [`$arrayElemAt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#mongodb-expression-exp.-arrayElemAt) operator.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me (I also tried ``$gt: 0``), it just gives "Network Error at createError"

As for the ``$arrayElemAt`` suggestion, I tried the following, but it didn't work either:
``{ [arrayName]: { $arrayElemAt: [ [0], { $exists: true } ] } }``

Comment: I updated my answer. `$size` doesn't work with `$gt` or any comparisons for some reason. We have to use an aggregate then.